# How to create a cross-platform C++ application in Netbeans?

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans, makefile, cross-platform

I am experiencing some difficulties while creating a simple "Hello world" cross-platform C++ app in Netbeans 8.0.1 for both Linux and Windows operating systems. I found very few instructions for Windows and none for Linux (my OS is Ubuntu 14.04).

My research over the Internet brought me to a conclusion that there should be created one more makefile for Windows OS. Usually, while creating a C++ project Netbeans kindly proposes us to create a makefile for us. And it's great, but it's just for Linux.

I stuck on Makefile creation (never done this before manually), so these were my steps to creating makefile for Windows:

1. Right Click on Project -> New -> Makefile
2. File Name: "Makefile-Windows" -> Next
3. Compiler: GNU Compilers, Platform: Windows -> Next
4. Base Directory: Project directory -> Next
5. Target Name: hello-world ( "Executable" radio button ) -> Add -> Next
6. Directory for All created files: GNU-amd64-Windows -> Next
7. Enter source files: main.cpp -> Next
8. Directories to Search for Include Files: Left empty -> Next
9. Choose libraries to link with: None, Link mode: Dynamic Linking -> Next
10. Libraries to link with: Left empty -> Next
11. How would you like your code to be built?: Dev. mode -> Next
12. , 13. Compiler options: Left default -> Finish

As a result, after making this fresh baked makefile in my GNU-amd64-Windows folder appears an object file (main.o) and an executable file (hello-world), but still executable only in Linux. When I try to run it in Windows command line, I get the error:

"Bad Command or file name"

Just in case here is my main.cpp content:

```
#include <iostream>
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If I have chosen a wrong way, then how should it be done?

Comment: Leaving aside the toolchain/toolkit differences, you cannot build a native executable that will run both on Linux and Windows; you have to compile once for every platform you intend to target.

Comment: The C++ code can be cross platform, the executable cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned Borgleader, only C++ code can be cross-platform. Here is my solution:

1. Firstly, we shouldn't use Linux GCC compiler for compiling Windows applications. That's why we need to install Windows compiler for Linux:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mingw32 mingw32-binutils mingw32-runtime
   ```
2. Secondly, while creating makefile we should specify alternative compiler. Use:

   ```
   /usr/bin/i586-mingw32msvc-g++
   ```

   insteat of default:

   ```
   g++
   ```
3. Finally, after making this makefile our output file becomes executable on Windows platforms.

Comment: I disagree entirely with this. If you want to support a linux application on windows then recompile the source code with Cygwin terminal on Windows. It will then become a Windows binary. This will work in most cases. Alternatively use macros to determine the compiler that is being used and compile the appropiate platform dependant code. This way it will be able to compile on both systems.